# which PIP version will support to which python version

Tags: python, pip

I gave this comment >Python get-pip.py

Error is coming like below

```
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=none, read=none, redirect=none, status=none)) after connection broken by'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifindHTTPSConnection.obj=..............at 0x045111B98>: Failed to establish a new connection : [Error 11001] get adderinfo failed')' : /simple/pip
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=none, read=none, redirect=none, status=none)) after connection broken by'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifindHTTPSConnection.obj=..............at 0x045111B98>: Failed to establish a new connection : [Error 11001] get adderinfo failed')' : /simple/pip
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=none, read=none, redirect=none, status=none)) after connection broken by'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifindHTTPSConnection.obj=..............at 0x045111B98>: Failed to establish a new connection : [Error 11001] get adderinfo failed')' : /simple/pip
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=none, read=none, redirect=none, status=none)) after connection broken by'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifindHTTPSConnection.obj=..............at 0x045111B98>: Failed to establish a new connection : [Error 11001] get adderinfo failed')' : /simple/pip
Warning: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=none, read=none, redirect=none, status=none)) after connection broken by'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifindHTTPSConnection.obj=..............at 0x045111B98>: Failed to establish a new connection : [Error 11001] get adderinfo failed')' : /simple/pip

Error: could not find the version that verifies the requirement pip (from version none)
Error: no matching distribution found for pip
```

Environment details:
Windows 10
Python 3.8 (inbuilt PIP)
I want to install package xlrd and xlwt

Help me.......

Answer (score 0):

pip3 should be ideally used for python 3. But if pip is inbuilt you don't need get-pip.py.

you can directly do

'pip install xlrd' or 'pip3 install xlrd'

to check where your pip is located, use 'where pip' or 'where pip3' from command line.

Comment: i can able to find PIP in my Python(its inbuilt) but when i was trying to install pip install xlrd, its not happening

Comment: not happening meaning, is it throwing an error during installation or is the import not happening, even after install?